# Trying to input a strcture, first time works great, second time crashes

Tags: c, loops, struct

Hi I'm inputting a structure of a family with children with those two structures:

```
typedef struct person {
    int id;
    char* firstName;
    int age;
}person;

typedef struct family {
    char* lastName;
    person father, mother;
    person* children;
    int numChildren;
}family;
```

EDIT: this is the edited function and it still crashes :

```
int initializeHouse(family **pdata)
{
    char temp[SIZE];
    int size, i, j;
    printf("enter the number of families\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    *pdata = (family*)malloc(sizeof( family)*size);
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the last name\n");
        scanf("%s", temp);
        (*pdata)[i].lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(temp) + 1));
        strcpy(pdata[i]->lastName, temp);
        printf("Enter the fathers first name\n");
        scanf("%s", temp);
        initPerson(temp, &pdata[i]->father.firstName);
        printf("enter the fathers ID\n");
        scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->father.id);
        printf("Enter the fathers age\n");
        scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->father.age);
        printf("Enter the mothers first name\n");
        scanf("%s", temp);
        initPerson(temp, &pdata[i]->mother.firstName);
        printf("enter the mothers ID\n");
        scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->mother.id);
        printf("Enter the mothers age\n");
        scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->mother.age);
        printf("enter the number of children");
        scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->numChildren);
        (*pdata)[i].children= (person*)malloc(sizeof(person)*(pdata[i]->numChildren));
        for (j = 0; j<pdata[i]->numChildren; j++)
        {
            printf("enter the kids name\n");
            scanf("%s", temp);
            initPerson(temp, &pdata[i]->children[j].firstName);
            printf("enter the kids ID\n");
            scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->children[j].id);
            printf("Enter the kids age\n");
            scanf("%d", &pdata[i]->children[j].age);

        }
    }
    return size;
}

void initPerson(char* str, char** fam)
{
    *fam = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str) + 1));
    strcpy(*fam, str);
}
```

EDIT: I changed the code and it still doesn't work, and it requires me to write some description so here it is ..

Comment: An aside: [Do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: why not? and why is that a problem?

Comment: Click on the link and read. That's why I provided the link.

Comment: @Lurker I did that *pdata=(family*)malloc(sizeof(family)*size; but why do I need to make each member as an allocated memory? that doesn't make sense. its a one dimensional array of structs

Comment: You need to allocate for an array of structure pointers, not an array of structures. So, `pdata = malloc(sizeof(family *)*size);`. And you still need to initialize each structure pointer as I indicated. `pdata[1]` and above all reference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: when I allocate a memory of pdata as a one dimensional array I create 0,1,2 many structures as I multiplied by the size, when I allocate again on pdata[1] what do I get from that? memory for what exactly?

Comment: @user 3121023 I edited the main function inside my post, and if im not mistaken those are the same things pdata[i]-> and (*pdata)[i]

Comment: `pdata` is of type `family **`.  I believe `pdata[x]` is treating it as an array of `family *` types rather than a pointer to an array of `family` types.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons , but isnt family* and family[] is the same thing?..

Comment: `pdata[i]->children = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person)*(pdata[i]->numChildren));` You can use `calloc` here.

Comment: @balki I prefer malloc as it works faster and I kinda have a problem with my fam[i]->lastName .. right now

Comment: Also, always check return value of `scanf`, so you can do something (such as just exit with error message) on parse error. Otherwise, funny things happen on invalid input, and trying to debug a program with funny things will often become an exercise in futility.

Comment: @AlexAlex: And don't edit the question after answers, it can make them meaningless to future visitors

Comment: You didn't change all the instances of `pdata[i]->` to `(*pdata)[i].`

Comment: @yano thank you, all of you guys thank you, you were right. Taught me a valuable lesson in structs, thank you!

Comment: @AlexAlex They are not the same.  An array of pointers will use an index offset to find a pointer and then dereference it to find the object.  a pointer to an array will need to be dereferenced to get the array, and then use an index offset to find the object in the array.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons, yes I understand it now, once again thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  int main() {
    int size;
    family *a = NULL;
    size=initializeHouse(&a);
  }
```

declares a pointer to a `family` structure. When you pass it's address

```
size = initializeHouse(&a);
```

the function gets it as a `family**`

Okay, we're all on the same page to this point. When you allocate the target of that pointer

```
*pdata = malloc(sizeof(family) * size);
```

then `*pdata` points to an allocated array of structs, not pointers to those structs. Each struct is accessed by `(*pdata)[i]`, which means -> dereference the double pointer `pdata` to get the address of the first element in the array, then access the array element with a subscript.

So your assignment should be

```
(*pdata)[i].lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(temp) + 1));
```

You use the dot `.` operator to access the members, because the result of the subscript access is a struct, *not* a pointer to a struct.

Comment: I edited it just like you said , still crashes... il post the code in the EDIT.

Comment: @AlexAlex: Don't change your comments -> it makes it very hard to follow

Comment: Sorry, I added the edited code to my post, still crashes tho, is there anything wrong there aswell?

Comment: @AlexAlex: You have to change all occurrences from `&pdata[i]` to `(*pdata)[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

This little example using `(*pdata)[i].` doesn't crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 40

typedef struct person {
    int id;
    char* firstName;
    int age;
}person;

typedef struct family {
    char* lastName;
    person father, mother;
    person* children;
    int numChildren;
}family;

int initializeHouse(family **pdata)
{
    char temp[SIZE];
    int size, i, j;
    printf("enter the number of families\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    *pdata = malloc(sizeof(family)*size);
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the last name\n");
        scanf("%39s", temp);
        (*pdata)[i].lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(temp) + 1));
        strcpy ( (*pdata)[i].lastName, temp);
    }
    return size;
}

int main ( void) {
    int size;
    family *a;
    size=initializeHouse(&a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you understand the memory layout.

```
family *fam;
family **pdata = &fam;

*pdata = (family*)malloc(sizeof(family)*size);
```

You have essentialy this: `fam` is a uninitialized pointer of type `family`.
`pdata` is a double pointer initialized with the address of `fam`. The malloc
call allocates space for `size` `family`-objects. By doing `*pdata = malloc(...)`
you are initializing `fam`.

This is the basic memory layout you have. `base` is the address returned by
malloc. `slf` is the size of `struct family` object, `fpl` is the size of a
**pointer** to a `struct family` object.

```
base = address returned by malloc
sfl = sizeof(struct family)
fpl = sizeof(struct family*)

base + 0          base + slf         base + 2 * slf
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|struct family    | struct family    | struct family    |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+

base + 0    base + fpl    base + 2*fpl base + 3*fpl base + 4*fpl
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| pdata[0]   | pdata[1]   | pdata[2]   | pdata[3]   | pdata[4]  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

The first row shows the memory in terms on `struct family` objects, the second
row shows you the same memory in terms on pointers (to `struct family` object).
**This** is very important distinction, because `pdata[i]` returns you a
pointer, not the object.

Remember `pdata` is a double pointer, `pdata[i]` is the equivalent to `pdata + i`,
that is the `i`th pointer begining at `base`.

Because the size of an `struct family` is defintitely different that the size of
a pointer, you see that the block don't align, that means
`base + slf != base + fpl`.

In the first iteration you are lucky, because `pdata[0]` and `(*pdata)[0]` are
the same. But `pdata[1]` and `*(pdata)[1]` are not the same. So doing
`pdata[1]->lastname` (instead of `(*pdata)[1].lastname`) you are accessing at a
wrong location in you allocated memory.

The easiest way to fix you code would be to change the `pdata[i]` in `(*pdata)[i]` as shown
in user3121023's answer.

---

**edit**

I see that user3121023 has retracted his answer. Basically it did:

```
printf("enter the fathers ID\n");
scanf("%d", &((*pdata)[i].father.id));
```

in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing [the pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450873) may have solved your problem. But the program has a lot of duplicate code and rewriting as follows would help you test a small portion and debug the program easily.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

typedef struct person {
    int id;
    char *firstName;
    int age;
} person;

typedef struct family {
    char *lastName;
    person father, mother;
    person *children;
    int numChildren;
} family;

void input_string(const char *prompt, char **where) {
    char temp[SIZE];
    printf("%s\n", prompt);
    scanf("%s", temp);
    *where = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1));
    strcpy(*where, temp);
}

void input_int(const char *prompt, int *where) {
    printf("%s\n", prompt);
    scanf("%d", where);
}

void input_person(const char *name, person *person) {
    char prompt[SIZE];
    sprintf(prompt, "Enter the %s's first name", name);
    input_string(prompt, &person->firstName);
    sprintf(prompt, "Enter the %s's ID", name);
    input_int(prompt, &person->id);
    sprintf(prompt, "Enter the %s's age", name);
    input_int(prompt, &person->age);
}

void input_family(family *fam) {
    input_string("Please enter the last name", &fam->lastName);
    input_person("father", &fam->father);
    input_person("mother", &fam->mother);
    input_int("Please enter the number of children", &fam->numChildren);
    fam->children = malloc(sizeof(person) * (fam->numChildren));
    for (int i = 0; i < fam->numChildren; i++) {
        input_person("kid", &(fam->children)[i]);
    }
}

int initializeHouse(family **families) {
    int size;
    input_int("Please enter the number of families", &size);
    *families = malloc(sizeof(family) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        input_family(&(*families)[i]);
    }
    return size;
}

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    family *a;
    size = initializeHouse(&a);
    printf("Successfully inputted %d families", size);
    return 0;
}
```